# Is there any way to record screen while running selenium test in c# except microsoft.expressions.encoder?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, screen-recording

I am thinking if there's other way to record screen while running selenium c# tests since microsoft.expressions.encoder now is not present in nuget packages.

It will be a really big help if you can show me the way or at least give me a hint. Thanks

Comment: Use OBS studio it is free and open source(Technical Knowledge Required) or use Bandicam paid but free trial(Easy to Use).

Comment: Is there a programming way?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @VaibhavDhasmana. sorry but still not

Comment: By any chance - did you find a solution?

Comment: @OlexiyDymashok yea I did by using this ScreenRecorderLib, tho the downside is it's actually a screen recorder rather than test recorder so if you run in headless mode then you're not recording you test, you're recording your screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Package:** Nunit.Video.Recorder

Out of two ways shown below, choose any one to record test scripts after installation of package

1. use [WatchDog(SaveInClass.FailedTestsOnly)] with [TestFixture] like [TestFixture, WatchDog(SaveInClass.FailedTestsOnly)]
2. use [Video(Mode = SaveMe.OnlyWhenFailed)] with [Test] like [Test, Video(Mode = SaveMe.OnlyWhenFailed)]

We do not get lot of options but this works just fine.

Comment: Hmmp, I think this only supports .Net Framework? Sorry forgot to mention that we're using .Net Core